# Can you explain this simply: $(a + b + c + \dotsc)^p = a^p + b^p + c^p + \dotsc + M(p)$?

Tags: number-theory

I also have a related question to this. I found out that $(a+b+c+\dotsc+n)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \dotsc + n^2 + 2$ (each number multiple once with itself but not considered again).
E.g. $(a+b+c+d)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd)$. From here I solved a few more example. I found that:

````
             ```a         a
             b         b 
             c         c 
             d         d  
             .         .
             .         .
             .         .
             n         n```
````

Suppose I have got n number of values then I will multiply each term by each next term, that is, a will be multiplied to $b,c,d,e, \dotsc,n$; $b$ will be multiplied with $c,d,e,\dotsc,n$; $c$ will be multiplied with $d,e,f,\dotsc,n$; and We will put them in a bracket and double the sum and that's how I have got this value.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$(a + b + c + \ldots + n)^p \equiv (a^p + b^p + c^p + \ldots + n^p) \pmod p$$

Comment: Additionally, you may check out the [Wikipedia page on the Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use multinomial theorem and the fact that

$$
\binom pk\equiv0\pmod p
$$

for all prime $p$ and $0<k<p$.